# I'm getting the location_id as null in shopify order api

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I created an order through shopify admin and added the customer details , when i executes the orders.json api , I'm getting location_id ="null"

Now i'm in need of location id to update the fulfillment status.

How to update the location id for an order if possible .This is my response when i created an order .

```
 {
"orders": [
    {
        "id": 568323571800,
        "email": "sample_test_123_gmail@gmail.com",
        "closed_at": null,
        "created_at": "2018-08-02T15:41:06+05:30",
        "updated_at": "2018-08-02T15:46:06+05:30",
        "number": 9,
        "note": "",
        "token": "a666eb3aea251cc585afc006cbf5b315",
        "gateway": "Cash on Delivery (COD)",
        "test": false,
        "total_price": "200.00",
        "subtotal_price": "200.00",
        "total_weight": 100,
        "total_tax": "0.00",
        "taxes_included": false,
        "currency": "INR",
        "financial_status": "pending",
        "confirmed": true,
        "total_discounts": "0.00",
        "total_line_items_price": "200.00",
        "cart_token": null,
        "buyer_accepts_marketing": false,
        "name": "#1009",
        "referring_site": null,
        "landing_site": null,
        "cancelled_at": null,
        "cancel_reason": null,
        "total_price_usd": "2.92",
        "checkout_token": null,
        "reference": null,
        "user_id": 23090102360,
        "location_id": null,
```

Comment: Facing a similar issue. I don't know the `location_id` which I am supposed to provide so have to look it up using the https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/inventory/location endpoint. It's a bit of a shame it doesn't default like it does in the Shopify UI so I can avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

`location_id` on an order will return `null` unless the order is made from a Shopify POS location in which case it will return the `location_id` associated with that location.

See the guide on fulfillments: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/managing-fulfillments

Answer (score 1):

location ID is tied to your inventory. First off, ensure you have set a location for your inventory. Second, make sure Shopify is set as your inventory management provider. If you now create an order for items managed by Shopify, you might see a location ID. Your test of creating a draft order like that might also not be fully integrated yet with Shopify locations? What happens when you book an order using the front end and not the API?

Comment: During Draft orders the location id is visible for the orders , whereas when an order is placed from the front-end its showing null value .
I'm trying to update the fulfillment status for the order using api , but without location id its showing location_id is required .

Comment: Sounds like you have discovered a super bug in Shopify. Have fun with that!

Comment: Really stuck in this , hope if you have answer for it pls reply

Comment: How to enable request fulfillment for an order , the fulfillment services for an order is of manual type so i need to trigger using api . Is it possible ? .

Answer (score 1):

To get locationId in order, need to pass inventoryQuantities input with location id and available quantity in productCreate Mutation.Then You will get locationId in order

```
{
  "input": {
     "title": "Demo Product",
     "descriptionHtml": "des",
     "productType": "type",
     "vendor": "vendor",
     "handle": "abc1",
     "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
     "variants": [
        {
          "title": "small",
          "price": 100,
          "compareAtPrice": 110,
          "position": 1,
          "inventoryQuantities": {
              "availableQuantity": 100,
              "locationId": "gid://shopify/Location/55274340513"
           },
          "inventoryItem": {
             "cost": 200,
             "tracked": true
           }
          }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find location_id from the */admin/api/2021-04/locations.json* API.

You will get response like this:

```
{
    "locations": [
        {
            "id": location_id,
            "name": "location_name",
            "address1": "location_address",
            "address2": null,
            "city": "Faisalabad",
            "zip": "38000",
            "province": "",
            "country": "PK",
            "phone": "",
            "created_at": "2021-02-25T15:34:18+05:00",
            "updated_at": "2021-02-25T15:34:20+05:00",
            "country_code": "PK",
            "country_name": "Pakistan",
            "province_code": null,
            "legacy": false,
            "active": true,
            "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Location/location_id",
            "localized_country_name": "Pakistan",
            "localized_province_name": null
        }
    ]
}
```